# Different timezone offsets for the same time zone in rails 4.0.4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone, timezone-offset

i have an `Event` model with a `start_time` column, typed `DateTime`.

I am trying to get the right time to display in a different time zone. e.g: `America/New_York`.
Here is the following code to demonstrate the difference between the time zone `utc_offset` in hours and the actual rendering value of the UTC date in the new timezone.

```
[3] pry(main)> Event.last.start_time
=> Wed, 28 May 2014 13:00:00 +0000
[5] pry(main)> Time.zone = "America/New_York"
=> "America/New_York"
[6] pry(main)> Time.zone.utc_offset / 3600
=> -5
[7] pry(main)> Event.last.start_time.in_time_zone(Time.zone)
=> Wed, 28 May 2014 09:00:00 EDT -04:00
```

Last line shows `-04:00` while the Time.zone utc offset is -5 hours. what is happening here?

Answer (score 1):

New York is in the US Eastern time zone.  Its *standard* offset is UTC-05:00, which is followed in the winter months.

In the summer months, [daylight saving time](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info) is in effect, and the offset becomes UTC-04:00.

[You can see the specific time zone offset changes for New York here.](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=2014)